# TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. when trying to append react element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to create a UI that allows users to download files from their computer to create an audio playlist. I'm trying to append a child that I created in my javascript code using `const li = <li ref={this.liRef}></li>`. For some reason this won't work when I try to append it with `ulRefNode.appendChild(li);` and `ulRefNode.appendChild(liNode);`. The `const liNode` also returns null. Are li and liNode node elements? Here's the code:

```
    class Download extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
     super(props)

     this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);

     this.inputRef = React.createRef();


     this.ulRef = React.createRef();

     this.destinationRef = React.createRef();

     this.liRef = React.createRef();



    }

       handleClick = () => {

    const node = this.inputRef.current;
    const destNode = this.destinationRef.current;
    const ulRefNode = this.ulRef.current;

    const liNode = this.liRef.current;

node.addEventListener('change', function() {
    var file;

    var ulAlreadyAdded = true;


for(var x = 0, xlen = this.files.length; x < xlen; x++) {
 console.log(this.files[x]);
 file = this.files[x];





   var reader = new FileReader();
   reader.onload = (e) => {




    const li = <li ref={this.liRef}></li>



    console.log("LINODE " + liNode);




    ulRefNode.appendChild(liNode);




}

reader.readAsDataURL(file);



 };   





});

};






render() {
return(

<div className="input">
<input onClick={this.handleClick} id="upload-file" className="inputName" type="file" multiple ref={this.inputRef}/>
<ReactAudioPlayer
  src="my_audio_file.ogg"
  autoPlay
  controls
/>
<div ref={this.destinationRef} id="destinationID"></div>
<ul ref={this.ulRef}></ul>


<output id="list"></output>









</div>

)


};





 }





    export default Download;
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, what you're trying to achieve is not meant to be done like that using React.

In React you should (in this case), read the data from whatever source you need, load it into state, and then render the UI you want to show the user.

I would suggest taking a look at the React tutorial before proceeding: https://reactjs.org/tutorial/tutorial.html

To give a quick idea about what the React component might look like, I've put together a small example:

```
import React from 'react';

class Download extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      files: [],
    };
  }

  componentDidMount {
    // Fetch your data (possibly asynchronously) and 
    // update the component state, which will cause
    // the component to re-render
    this.setState({
      files: [{ name: 'File A' }, { name: 'File B' }],
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {this.state.files.map((file, index) => (
          <li key={index}>
            {file.name}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

*Note for whomever might stumble upon this: Beware, that I've used some practices in this code snippet that might not be considered best practices, but helps simplify the explanation of the code (e.g. how `setState` is used and using an `index` as `key` in the render method's loop.*

Comment: I got to work somewhat but now I'm only getting the last item in the array shown and only once on the page.

Comment: Hi @DDavis25, sorry to hear that. I think that might be a separate issue. If it persists, feel free to open a new question with it

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59289900/how-do-i-add-each-item-from-my-for-loop-onto-my-array-reactjs